# sql add one to field value

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having problems with an INT field. The thing is when I print the value on screen is OK but when I update the database register adds one more.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "SELECT id_ad, ad_printed FROM ads WHERE (ad_type = \"990x90\" OR (ad_type = \"728x90\" OR ad_type = \"250x90\")) AND ad_date_start <= \"$today\" AND ad_date_finish >= \"$today\"";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $new_value = $row['ad_printed'] + 1;
    $curr_id = $row['id_ad'];
    $query_upd = "UPDATE ads SET ad_printed = '".$new_value."' WHERE id_ad = '".$curr_id."' LIMIT 1;";
    $upd = mysqli_query($link, $query_upd); 
}
```

Does anybody know what could be happened?
I.E. If the original value is 26, the new value must be 27. The `$new_value` is 27 but it registers as 28... :(

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` returns?

Comment: is it possible that you have several records with same id_ad?

Comment: is id_ad unique? if not this is your problem you have to update all of them and remove the LIMIT 1....

Comment: This is the var_dump return: array(10) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id_ad"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(24) "images/ads/top990x90.jpg" ["ad_file"]=> string(24) "images/ads/top990x90.jpg" [2]=> string(0) "" ["ad_file_alt"]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(2) "32" ["ad_printed"]=> string(2) "32" [4]=> string(8) "pega top" ["ad_name"]=> string(8) "pega top" }

Comment: No. I have just one record in the DB! :( I tried to put an echo "hello" and it prints just once... I'm lost :(

Comment: The id is auto_increment

Comment: I removed the LIMIT 1 but it's still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

if you like to increase a value in sql don't wrap the column value into quotes, otherwise sql handle the column value as a string. please make sure your column type is correct like `integer` and not `varchar`

```
UPDATE ads SET ad_printed = (ad_printed + 1) WHERE id_ad = '".$curr_id."' LIMIT 1;
```

//edit

if you pass variables directly into sql please look at the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function to prevent sql injections.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I put: $query_upd = "UPDATE ads SET ad_printed = (ad_printed + 1) WHERE id_ad = '".$row['id_ad']."' LIMIT 1"; but it still increases 2 instead of 1... :(

Comment: then your query ``SELECT id_ad, ad_printed FROM...`` returns more rows and your loop executes the sql functions twice or more on the same dataset id. your script looks fine - i think you should look into your database and verify what data php gets in return.

Comment: It's very strange because I have another field called ad_clicked (when the user click on the ad it increments 1) and it works perfectly... but this field (it must increase when the page prints) it doesn't. I have just one record in the DB and the id is auto_increment. So it's unique... :(